# Возможно ли отслеживать изменение переменной

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Есть ли в студии встроенные средства для отслеживания изменения переменной, что бы отладчик останавливался в момент когда изменилось значение переменной?

Comment: A breakpoint зачем?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да, есть - `Debug -> NewBreakpoint -> DataBrekpoint`.

**UPD**
Наиболее исчерпывающая документация по Data Breakpoint:
[Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2017)
[GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html)

Comment: Круто, не думал что такие средства вообще есть :) А в Qt , или в gdb что-то подобное есть? (под линуксом)

Comment: @zcorvid Да, в GDB тоже есть [подобный инструмент](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html)

Comment: Прикольная штука, не знал.  Правда оказывается только в плюсах есть, а в шарпе нет. И ещё можно только 4 штуки назначить (по крайней мере [в 2010 студии](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/350dyxd0(v=vs.100))). Ответу бесспорно апвоут, но если будет возможность - добавьте ссылку на документацию.